# How do you get Indonesian Rupiah currency formater with `getCurrencyInstance` in Android? What about other locales such as Albanian Lek?

Tags: android, currency, number-formatting, currency-formatting, numberformatter

Basically, I want to format a string number into an appropriate looking local format.
For example, "15000" into looking more or less like my locale currency format.
i.e "Rp.15.000"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the problem arises since your Locale constant is not readily available.
That is, there is no such thing as `Locale.INDONESIAN`, or `Locale.ALBANIAN`, or `Locale.LATVIAN`.

TL;DR for Indonesian Rupiah format:

```
Locale myIndonesianLocale = new Locale("in", "ID");
NumberFormat formater = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(myIndonesianLocale);
```

That's for Indonesian locale, what about other locales?

Go to: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-jre8-suported-locales.html
(please pay attention to Language Tag).

For Albanian locale pair: sq-AL:
`Locale myAlbanianLocale = new Locale("sq", "AL");`

For Latvian locale pair: lv-LV
`Locale myAlbanianLocale = new Locale("lv", "LV");`

And so on.

Comment: is this accepted answer? where are the votes?